# Returning two columns from different tables by joining on one column

Tags: mysql, join

I have 200+ telephone numbers in Table A which I require address data for from Table B. Table B has 5 million+ rows of data and the matching field is PhoneNumber. I have written some SQL which does part of what I want but it is only matching up the first record in Table A and I have null values for all of the others???

Please help

```
SELECT TableA.TelephoneNumber, TableB.Address
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TableB
     ON TelephoneNumber = PhoneNumber
```

Comment: You will get `NULL` values where the phone number is not in `TableB`.

Comment: That's what I thought but when I look up the next Telephone Number in TableA in TableB I can see it with an address beside it. It's almost like it has found a match for the first record and then stopped looking for the rest...

Comment: . . There is probably a subtle difference in the format of the numbers that is causing a mismatch.

Comment: Checked that. The format of all the numbers in Table A are the same..

Answer (score 0):

If you only want matching records, you should use an inner join, not an outer join:

```
SELECT TableA.TelephoneNumber, TableB.Address
FROM   TableA 
JOIN   TableB ON TelephoneNumber = PhoneNumber
```

Comment: This answer matches the first row in TableA and nothing else.

Comment: Are you **sure** the data actually matches? The query results (both this one and the one in the OP) suggest they don't.